# Non normality on confidence interval

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, confidence-interval

I've constructed a confidence interval for one mean under the assumption that the distribution follows a normal distribution. I am to comment on the importance of normality for the confidence interval. If there are consequences for the confidence interval when data is non normal distributed, what are they?

Comment: If you know the variance of the distribution, then using a standard normal distribution for the confidence interval works, but if the variance is unknown, then you need to use a $t$-test

Comment: Yes, and I've done that. I need to comment on the validity of the interval if the distribution was non normal